# Return values to multiple fields — using an Arcade calculation attribute rule in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, fields-attributes, arcade, attribute-rules

ArcGIS Pro 2.9:

Is there a way to return values to **multiple fields** using an Arcade calculation attribute rule?

For example, return values to the following fields, all within a single expression/rule:

1. Shape
2. Midpoint
3. Vertex_Count

---

There's a section in the docs about [Returning values from scripts](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/#returning-values-from-your-script).

But I can't quite wrap my head around how to return values to *multiple* fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: [Attribute rule dictionary keywords](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/overview/attribute-rule-dictionary-keywords.htm)

> You can return a result as a dictionary to update **multiple fields** of
> the feature. When returning a result as a dictionary, the target field
> in the attribute rule is optional.
>
> ```
> return {
>     //result is a dictionary
>     "result": {
>         "attributes": {
>             "field1": 'field1', //updates field1 in the $feature 
>             "field2": 11 //updates field2 in the $feature 
>         },
>         "geometry": Rotate($feature) //updates geometry in $feature
>     }
>
> }
> ```